# expand matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, expand

I would like to expand matrix row by row under a conditional statement without initializing the matrix. In C++, simply I use `std::vector` and `push_back` method without initializing the size of the vector in C++. However, I want to do same scenario in Matlab. This is my pseudo code

```
for i = 1:lengt(data)
    if ( condition )
        K = [data(1) data(2) i]
end

K
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume from the above that **data** is an Nx2 matrix, and that you only want to save the  rows that satisfy some condition, then you almost have the correct code to update your **K** matrix without having to initialize it to some size:

```
K = [];  % initialize to an empty matrix

for i=1:size(data,1)   % iterate over the rows of data
    if (condition)
        % condition is satisfied so update K
        K = [K ; data(i,:) i];
    end
end

K % contains all rows of data and the row number (i) that satisfied condition
```

Note that to get all elements from a row, we use the colon to say get all column elements from row **i**.

Comment: I did consider this to be the answer just because its simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume some working code to resemble your pseudo-code.

```
%// Original code
for i = 1:10
    if rand(1)>0.5
        data1 = rand(2,1)
        K = [data1(1) data1(2) i]
    end
end
```

**Changes for "pushing data without initialization/pre-allocation":**

1. To save data at each iteration we keeping on "stacking" data along a chosen dimension. This could be thought of as pushing data. For a 2D case, use either a "row vector push" or a "column vector push". For this case we are assuming a former case.
2. We don't index into K using the original iterator, but use a custom one,
   that only increments when the `condition` is satisfied.

The code below must make it clear.

```
%// Modified code
count = 1; %// Custom iterator; initialize it for the iteration when condition would be satisfied for the first time
for i = 1:10
    if rand(1)>0.5
        data1 = rand(2,1)
        K(count,:) = [data1(1) data1(2) i] %// Row indexing to save data at each iteration
        count = count +1; %// We need to manually increment our custom iterator
    end
end
```