# Expand an array by filling in with current values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a fairly simple issue and I just want to know if there's an easy way to do it in MATLAB (i.e. a function to do this rather than writing out loops or something myself).

Let's say I have a timeseries where Time is `1:1:1000` and Data is `2 * (1:1:1000)` and I want to expand the array by making the Time and Data vector finer.  Let's say that I want Time to be `1:0.1:1000` and Data to be `2 * (1:0.1:1000)`.  Is there an easy way to tell MATLAB that to repeat the values of each vector `10` times (from `1 / 0.1 = 10`) so that I can have something like this?:

`Time: [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`

`Data: [2, 4, 6, 8, ...]`

to:

`Time: [1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, ...]`

`Data: [2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   4, ...]`

Comment: You can use `repmat(Data, 10,1)(:)` for `Data`, and if you know your time series is spaced evenly, you can regenerate it as you mentioned

Comment: You might need to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963605/expand-matrix-in-matlab

Comment: Almost the  same question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1947889/2586922

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of `reshape()` and `repmat()` as follow:

```
Data = [2, 4, 6, 8, ...] % As stated in the question. 
Data = reshape(repmat(Data, 10, 1), 1, []);
```

This is more time-efficient than the others like `kron()` or combination of `sort()` and `repmat()`.

Two simulations were done and the results are shown in the following figures.

First: Simulation time vs. length of `Data`. Here I used N=100 instead of 10.

[image]

Second: Simulation time vs. repetition factor. Length of `Data` is 10000.

[image]

So you can select the best one according to the simulation results.

Answer (score 1):

As seb proposed, you can use the function `repmat`. Here what I would do:

```
Data = [2, 4, 6, 8, ...];
Data = sort(repmat(Data,1,10));
```

Comment: How about expanding it out to a data matrix rather than a vector if I wanted to repeat it via rows?

Comment: @celestialorb Do you mean as in `Data = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2; ...
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4; ...`??

Comment: Let's say I had position data that corresponded to each time instance.  Such as `data = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]` for `time = [1 2 3]` and I want to expand that to `data = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 4 5 6; 4 5 6]` and `time = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]`.  Basically a way to just repeat the rows of data and elements of time by some integer X (X = 3 in the case given in this comment).

Comment: You would use `repmat` again and specify how many tiles of the matrix you would want repeated.

Comment: @m_power: your approach assumes monotonic increasing data -> not quite generic solution. Use `Data = repmat(Data,1,10); Data = Data(:);` instead. It's faster also.

Comment: I am not sure where the `sort` is coming from, but it's not needed.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I assumed from the OP question that the data is increasing.

Comment: @seb: Doing `repmat(Data,1,10)(:)` throws an error. Also, using `sort`, even if slower, makes the code cleaner and more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use repmat

```
interval_size = 10;
Data = 2*(1:1:1000);

out_data = repmat(Data,interval_size,1);
out_data = out_data(:)';
```

Answer (score 0):

Example Data:

```
time=1:50
data=2:2:100
t2=1:.1:50.9
```

For time=1:n this is very simple:

```
data(:,floor(t2))
```

If your original data has another time scale, use this:

```
[a,b]=ismember(floor(t2),time)
data(:,b)
```